# Physical Chemistry: Calculating ΔG, ΔH, ΔS on a given equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, electrochemistry

This question was brought in class, but I have no clue if my answer is correct or not.

I wonder if you guys can double check my answer.

> Between $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$ and $90 ^\circ C$, the potential of a cell with $n=2$, is given by:
>   $$\frac{E}{v} = 0.35510 - 0.3422\times 10^{-4} T - 3.2347\times 10^{-6}T^2$$
>
> where $T$ is the Celsius temperature. Calculate $\Delta G, \Delta H,
>  \Delta S$ for the cell at $50 ° C$.

My answer:

\begin{align}
  E &= 0.35510 - 0.3422\times 10^{-4}\cdot 50 - 3.2347\times 10^{-6} (50)^2  \\
    &= 0.35510 - 1.711\times 10^{-3} - 8.08675\times 10^{-3} \\
    &= \pu{0.3453 V}\\[2ex]
\left(\frac{\partial\Delta G}{\partial T} \right)_P 
   &= -\Delta S\\
   &= -nF\left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_P \\
   &= -nF \cdot (-0.3422\cdot 10^{-4} -6.4694\cdot10^{-6}\cdot T) \\
   \text{at $50 °C$,} \implies &= nF\cdot(3.5769\cdot10^{-4}) \\
   &= 69.02 = -\Delta S\\
   \therefore \Delta S &= \pu{-69.02 J//mol} \\[2ex]
 \Delta G &= nFE \\
   &= -2\cdot \pu{96485 C//mol}\cdot \pu{0.3453 V}\\
   &= \pu{-66633 kJ//mol}\\[2ex]
\Delta H &= \Delta G + T\Delta S\\
   &= \pu{-66633 kJ//mol} 
      + (\pu{50 ^\circ C} + \pu{273.15 K})\cdot(\pu{-69.02 J//mol})\\
   &= \pu{88.926 kJ}
\end{align}

Comment: Method/numbers  seems to be ok except for little typo; it should be  $\Delta G =-nFE$.